# HQL for perfectly working nested SQL

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, nested, hql

Can Anybody help in writing HQL query for below perfectly working SQL query

```
select d2.user_id,d2.push_token,d2.registration_date from device_registration d2,(
select max(d1.registration_date) as registration_date,d1.push_token from device_registration d1
where  d1.push_Token != 'null' and d1.push_Token is not null and d1.push_Token!=''
group by d1.push_token) d3
where d2.push_token=d3.push_token and d2.registration_date=d3.registration_date 
order by d2.registration_date asc
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the query, reformatted a bit:

```
select d2.user_id, d2.push_token, d2.registration_date
from device_registration d2 join
     (select max(d1.registration_date) as registration_date, d1.push_token
      from device_registration d1
      where d1.push_Token <> 'null' and d1.push_Token is not null and d1.push_Token <> ''
      group by d1.push_token
     ) d3
     on d2.push_token = d3.push_token and d2.registration_date = d3.registration_date 
order by d2.registration_date asc;
```

It is essentially getting the maximum registration date for each `push_token`.  The following should follow HQL standards:

```
select 2.*
from device_registration d
where not exists (select 1
                  from device_registration d2
                  where d2.push_token = d.push_token and d2.registration_date > d.registration_date
                 )
order by d.registration_date desc;
```